# Cocos2d-x game doesn't respond to touch on iOS9

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-x, ios9, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've developed a game in Cocos2d-X for iPads. I've tested it on several iPads and it worked great but after I published it to the App Store a few users complained that the game is completely unresponsive, meaning, all the animations are running but the game doesn't respond to touch events.

I have tried reproducing the problem but even if I use the exact same device with the exact same iOS version I still can't reproduce it. All the users who complained are running various versions of iOS9.

I have quite a few installs so it appears the problem only affects a small percentage of my users, but it still affects them. And for these users the game is always unresponsive, no matter how many times they run it or install\uninstall it.

I'm working with cocos2d-x 3.6.

Did anyone encounter such a problem or have any idea what might cause it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, the problem was the MFMailComposeViewController. I mistakenly attempted to allocate it at startup without checking its canSendMail method. Apparently in iOS 9 it causes some kind of problem that blocks touches to my app.